# Как сделать загрузку изображений на сервере php, mysql?

Tags: php

Делаю простенький интернет магазин. Сделал уже добавления товаров через форму. Единственный вопрос это как сделать что бы при загрузке изображений она загружалась на сервере в папку images/

Comment: https://dmitrylavrik.ru/blog/php/zagruzka-izobrazhenij-na-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основную идею можно прочитать [в статье на php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php). В целом, есть массив `$_FILES[]`, с которым и придётся работать:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Файл корректен и был успешно загружен.\n";
} else {
    echo "Возможная атака с помощью файловой загрузки!\n";
}

echo 'Некоторая отладочная информация:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

В базе лучше хранить название файлов в виде строк. Завести переменную с путём на папу и дёргать файл, комбинируя полный путь до папки и имя файла.